# LINQ for LIKE queries of array elements

Tags: linq, arrays, linq-to-sql

Let's say I have an array, and I want to do a LINQ query against a varchar that returns any records that have an element of the array anywhere in the varchar.

Something like this would be sweet.

`string[] industries = { "airline", "railroad" }`

var query = from c in contacts where c.industry.LikeAnyElement(industries) select c

Any ideas?

Comment: LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities, LINQ to Objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually an example I use in my "[Express Yourself](http://www.dddsouthwest.com/Agenda/tabid/55/Default.aspx)" presentation, for something that is hard to do in regular LINQ; As far as I know, the easiest way to do this is by writing the predicate manually. I use the example below (note it would work equally for `StartsWith` etc):

```
    using (var ctx = new NorthwindDataContext())
    {
        ctx.Log = Console.Out;
        var data = ctx.Customers.WhereTrueForAny(
            s => cust => cust.CompanyName.Contains(s),
            "a", "de", "s").ToArray();
    }
// ...
public static class QueryableExt
{
    public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereTrueForAny<TSource, TValue>(
        this IQueryable<TSource> source,
        Func<TValue, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>> selector,
        params TValue[] values)
    {
        return source.Where(BuildTrueForAny(selector, values));
    }
    public static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> BuildTrueForAny<TSource, TValue>(
        Func<TValue, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>> selector,
        params TValue[] values)
    {
        if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
        if (values == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("values");
        if (values.Length == 0) return x => true;
        if (values.Length == 1) return selector(values[0]);

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");
        Expression body = Expression.Invoke(selector(values[0]), param);
        for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            body = Expression.OrElse(body,
                Expression.Invoke(selector(values[i]), param));
        }
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(body, param);
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice! (Please enter at least 10 characters.)

Answer (score 4):

```
from c in contracts 
where industries.Any(i => i == c.industry)
select c;
```

something like that. use the any method on the collection.

Comment: This throws an exception in LINQ to SQL. It can be written as "where industries.Contains(c.industry)", which translates as "c.industry IN ('airline', 'railroad')", but he wants a LIKE comparison.

Answer (score 4):

`IEnumerable.Contains()` translates to SQL **IN** as in:

```
WHERE 'american airlines' IN ('airline', 'railroad') -- FALSE
```

`String.Contains()` which translates to SQL **LIKE %...%** as in:

```
WHERE 'american airlines' LIKE '%airline%' -- TRUE
```

If you want the contacts where the contact's industry is LIKE (contains) any of the given industries, you want to combine both Any() and String.Contains() into something like this:

```
string[] industries = { "airline", "railroad" };

var query = from c in contacts 
            where industries.Any(i => c.Industry.Contains(i))
            select c;
```

However, combining both Any() and String.Contains() like this is *NOT* supported in LINQ to SQL. If the set of given industries is small, you can try something like:

```
where c.Industry.Contains("airline") ||
      c.Industry.Contains("railroad") || ...
```

Or (although normally not recommended) if the set of contacts is small enough, you could bring them all from the DB and apply the filter with LINQ to Objects by using contacts.AsEnumerable() or contacts.ToList() as the source of the query above:

```
var query = from c in contacts.AsEnumerable()
            where industries.Any(i => c.Industry.Contains(i))
            select c;
```

Answer (score 1):

it will work if you build up the query as follows:

var query = from c in contacts.AsEnumerable() 
            select c;

query = query.Where(c=> (c.Industry.Contains("airline")) || (c.Industry.Contains("railroad")));

you just need to programmatically generate the string above if the parameters airline and railroad are user inputs. This was in fact a little more complicated than I was expecting. See article - http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, LIKE is not supported in LINQ to SQL as per here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882677.aspx

To get around this, you will have to write a stored procedure which will accept the parameters you want to use in the like statement(s) and then call that from LINQ to SQL.

---

It should be noted that a few of the answers suggest using Contains.  This won't work because it looks to see that the entire string matches the array element.  What is being looked for is for the array element to be contained in the field itself, something like:

```
industry LIKE '%<element>%'
```

As Clark has mentioned in a comment, you could use a call to IndexOf on each element (which should translate to a SQL call):

```
string[] industries = { "airline", "railroad" }

var query = 
    from c in contacts 
    where
        c.industry.IndexOf(industries[0]) != -1 ||
        c.industry.IndexOf(industries[1]) != -1
```

If you know the length of the array and the number of elements, then you could hard-code this.  If you don't, then you will have to create the Expression instance based on the array and the field you are looking at.

Comment: I knew that.. my bad.. a charindex != -1 for each item in the array would do just fine.

Comment: actually LIKE is somewhat supported in LINQ to SQL. "where c.industry.Contains("airline")" works and translates to "WHERE c.industry LIKE '%airline%'. But he wants LIKE any of the given values, not just one.