# LINQ 2 SQL - using a C# entity collection and SqlMethods.Like together

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a collection of headers, each which contains a collection of objects, each of which contains a collection of metadata key value pairs. eg

```
> Header
>     -> Object
>         -> Key value pair
>         -> Key value pair
>     -> Object
>         -> Key value pair
>         -> Key value pair
```

I want to return all headers, which contain an object, which contains a certain key value pair in the metadata, using SQL wildcards (using SqlMethods.Like).

I have written a LINQ 2 SQL query below with two levels of subqueries which handles the scenario

```
string filePath = "ab%cd";
var dbHeaders = from h in _repository.GetHeaders()
                    where
                         (from o in h.Objects
                          where 
                                (from mdp in o.MetaDataPairs 
                                 where mdp.Key == Constants.FilePath && SqlMethods.Like(mdp.Value.ToLower(), filePath)) 
                                 select mdp
                                ).Any()
                          select o).Any()
                     select h;
```

This works fine.

The problem arises when I have a list of possible search values to search on. Ie I want to find objects containing a metadata value from a list of possible matches, not just a single match. I tried the below.

```
var filePaths = new List<string> { "ab%cd", "ef%gh" };
var dbHeaders = from h in _repository.GetHeaders()
                    where
                         (from o in h.Objects
                          where 
                                (from mdp in o.MetaDataPairs 
                                 where mdp.Key == Constants.FilePath && filePaths.Any(fp => SqlMethods.Like(mdp.Value.ToLower(), fp)) 
                                 select mdp
                                ).Any()
                          select o).Any()
                     select h;
```

but because SQLMethods.Like is contained within Filepaths.Any() it doesn't work. as it has to occur natively in the LINQ 2 SQL query.

How can I modify the top query to match, using SQL Like operator, so that it checks against a list of string search tokens, not a single one?

UPDATE: Error message below

> Assert.IsFalse failed. An unexpected error occurred: LINQ to Entities
>   does not recognize the method 'Boolean Like(System.String,
>   System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.

Comment: Are you getting a not supported exception? Or just not the expected results?

Comment: Error message added to question

Comment: Maybe try SqlFunctions.PatIndex(strPattern, target) > 0? My recollection is that SqlMethods.Like doesn't work with linq to entity

Comment: I thought the above query was LINQ 2 SQL? Am I being thick, what makes it LINQ to entity?

Comment: I don't know your setup but the exception says linq to entities. I know that SqlMethods.Like gives the same error for my linq to entity setup.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, as you've mentioned, that once you put the `SqlMethods.Like` in the `filePaths.Any` it throws an exception.
That's because `SqlMethods.Like` is not supported in linq-to-entity, and `filePath` is an entity.

You need to, somehow, dynamically create multiple `OR` statements with `SqlMethods.Like`.

I've found a very similar question and an interesting answer that should help:
[How can I add variable count of SqlMethods.Like() in one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609963/how-can-i-add-variable-count-of-sqlmethods-like-in-one-query)

The solution takes advantage of [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) from *C# 6.0 in a Nutshell*.

I believe you could adapt your code into something like the following:
*I didn't test the code, ofcourse.*

```
var filePaths = new List<string> { "ab%cd", "ef%gh" };
var likeExpression = PredicateBuilder.False<MetaDataPairClassName>();
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
    likeExpression = likeExpression.Or(mdp => 
    SqlMethods.Like(mdp.Value.ToLower(), filePath));
}

var dbHeaders = from h in _repository.GetHeaders()
                where
                   (from o in h.Objects
                     where 
                        (from mdp in o.MetaDataPairs
                         .Where(mdp.Key == Constants.FilePath)
                         .Where(likeExpression)) 
                         select mdp
                              ).Any()
                     select o).Any()
                select h;
```