# LINQ: Multiple LIKE clauses in a single predicate

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'd like to do a LINQ query that can compare multiple variables to a single string. I've seen [LINQ for LIKE queries of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698379/linq-for-like-queries-of-array-elements), and it's helpful, but not quite. I need the reverse.

What I'd like to do is the following: let's say I have a `Company` object with both `Name` and `Address`. I also have a string `keyword`. Then, I'd like to find all `Company`s in a list that have the `keyword` in either their `Name` or `Address`. In SQL it would be...

```
SELECT * FROM Company
WHERE Name LIKE '%keyword%' OR Address LIKE '%keyword%'
```

I've been using Entity Framework, and I've tried the following: `context.Companies.Where(x => new string[] { x.Name, x.Address }.Contains(keyword)`, as well as `context.Companies.Where(x => new string[] { x.Name, x.Address }.Any(r => r.Contains(keyword))`, but neither were successful. The first one gives me an `IN` clause, and the second one... I don't know what it does, but it doesn't give me what I want.

I'm sorry I don't have a very in-depth understanding of Expressions (yet); I wished I was able to write my own custom Expressions from scratch, but *scratch it* I can't just yet... Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 6):

Any reason for not just using the `||` operator?

```
context.Companies.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(keyword) || 
                             x.Address.Contains(keyword))
```

I'd expect this to be translated into your original SQL.

Comment: Just for convenience and readability's sake... I wouldn't want an entire list of `||`

Comment: @matt: Well, there are ways of creating expressions like that programmatically (see http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) - but the case you gave only has two values, so I'd *absolutely* just use `||` there. Even if the version you gave of creating an array with the name and the address in worked, I'd say it's far less readable than the code in my answer. If you'd asked about a scenario with more properties - or a variable number of properties - I'd have given a different answer.

Comment: Ah... I see. Well I wrote that just for illustration purposes, my objects have more than just two properties, and it'd be a system-wide implementation (because I'm doing it for search). I've seen that website before, and I saw the `.Or` thingy, but I still don't get how I'm going to use it to write something pluggable into my current LINQ statements.

I'm not asking for hard and fast code, but I kinda have no clue how to get started with these Expressions... Kinda feels like learning C# all over again.